# Anyone know what faucet brand this is? Its a ball tub valve, appears pretty old

Tags: plumbing, shower, faucet, bathtub

I have  leaky tub faucet that's pretty old, went to big box and realized I had no idea what to get. Anyone know what brand/model this might be? [image]

Comment: You might just need to take it apart and clean it, crud in the valve can build up over time

Answer (score 1):

A single handle faucet will have seals called o-rings they wear out over time, dissemble and take the the o-rings in to a plumbing or big box store and they should have replacements there are not that many different sizes of o rings in the range used for faucets.